# Reordering different feature classes fom different layers in ArcMap Legend

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend

I have 6 layers in my TOC.
2 are polygon, 2 are line, and 2 are point feature classes.

TOC looks like this:

1. Well (water) - point
2. Pump (Gas) - point
3. Pipes (Water) - line
4. Gaspipes (Gas) - line
5. Gas field (Gas) - polygon
6. Lake (Water) – polygon

I would like to create Legend in my layout but I need to group different feature classes from different layers.
Legend should look like this:

**WATER**
X Well
-- Pipes
O Lake

**GAS**
X Pump
-- GasPipes
O Gas Field

Can this be done without converting legend to graphic?

Answer (score 1):

While you can solve half of this by reordering your layers in the Legend properties, you cannot group layers under headings in an ArcMap legend.  You can work around this though by creating **two** legends, one showing *Water* layers and the other showing *Gas* layers, and then just align them nicely in your layout.

1. Create a legend and select only your Water layers, and order them into the order you want, and click Next

   [image]
2. Rename your Legend, and if required change the font size of your legend title, and click Next

   [image]
3. Click Next through to finish (adjusting other Legend properties as required)
4. Repeat steps 1-3 for Gas

   [image]

   [image]
5. Select your two legends, and align them using Right-click on legend > Align > Left, and reposition your legends together as required

   [image]

You should now have two legends aligned and together will look like a single legend, and will be grouped and headed with Water and Gas

[image]